# F# sprintf won't print in interactive console

Tags: f#

I'm trying to print an int using the F# interactive console.

```
let x = sprintf "%d", 3
printf x
```

gives:

> stdin(12,8): error FS0001: The type '(int -> string) *
>   System.Numerics.BigIntege r' is not compatible with the type
>   'Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a>'

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

```
let x = sprintf "%d" 3
printf "%s" x
```

because the way you wrote it x is tuple of a function and a number

Comment: This won't work. `printf` doesn't expect a string, but a format. `printf "%s" x` will work, or just `System.Console.Write x`.

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz - It doesn't work either way. The format string must be a string literal, not a variable, as it is converted into a `TextWriterFormat<'a>` at compile time. That's why `printf "hi"` works but `printf x` does not.